# Why is the dropdown Application greyed out in Run user flow?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using Azure Active Directory B2C. I registered my application. I have now trying to create a sign up sign in User flow. However, I unable to use the newly appended authority url in my js client. `...-724716ee2ac2/b2c_1_susi` I get a http status code 'failed'. When I try click the button 'Run user flow' all the drop down fields are greyed out and nothing happens when I click run. Any idea what else is needed?

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows) indicates that I should be able to test the user flow by selecting the application and hit run.

[image]

Comment: Would you please provide some screenshots?

Comment: picture has been added.

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: I have same problem. any update?

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69206653/461099

Answer (score 3):

Create a B2C application registration. Whatever app reg you created, it’s not a B2C app reg.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga

Comment: I've done all of this, but it's still blank; there's definitely more to it than that.

Comment: The only cause is that the App registration was not configured as per that article.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test or authenticate with user flows, the option "Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)" must be selected, otherwise it won't be able to test the user flow using the registered app.

[image: screen shot of selecting the correct Supported account types option]

Answer (score -1):

I came across this too, the documentation fails to mention you need to create a third application registration. This is your SPA/MVC application registration. Once you have done this you can test the policies.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same with running the user flow and what helped me was enabling "Allow public client flows"
[image: Allow public client flows]