# Azure B2C user flow does not show any Application

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Just registered the first app in Azure B2C and a first User Flow.

To check the flow I clicked "Run user flow" but all fields and drop downs in the popup are empty.

Shouldn't there be at least the one app registered in the drop down ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When registering the application using **Azure AD B2C > App Registrations > +New Registration**, you need to select the option `Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)` under **Supported account types** section as highlighted below:

[image]

If you select one of the other two options during app registration, the application will not be listed in the drop down when you click on "Run user flow".

Comment: Is it possible to change it once the app registration is created or you have to delete and recreate it entirely?

Comment: You can change it by updating the signInAudience property in the Manifest of the application, but it will impact other properties as well. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/supported-accounts-validation for more details.